# Wordpress Advanced Custom Field - display image in specified size

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I followed instructions from ACL website to  display image in specific size but it doesn't show at all. I set the image to Object in repeater field, this is my code:

```
$image_1 = get_sub_field('image');

<?php if($image_1): ?>
 <img src="<?php echo $image_1['sizes']['medium']; ?>" alt="" />
<?php endif; ?>
```

when I remove the following it displays image fine, but full size of course:

```
['sizes']['medium']
```

What’s the problem? Should there somewhere be [‘url’] added? 
I am always confused with those images in ACL.

Answer (score 2):

You must indicate your image index, because usually you will run this code inside a loop, so image_1 will be an array, to access the first image you need to add the image position, image_1[0]['sizes']['medium'] .. I tried this code and it works fine.

```
if ( have_rows( 'repeater_field', $homepage_id ) ) {

    $i = 0;
    // loop through the rows of data
    while ( have_rows( 'repeater_field', $homepage_id ) ) {
        the_row();
        //Get imgs
        $imgs[$i]['img_test'] = get_sub_field( 'img_test' );
        $i++;
    }
}


echo "src = ".$imgs[0]['img_test']["sizes"]["medium"];
```

Comment: I went for different approach, tidied up my code, but your answer was also good.

Answer (score 0):

ACF have option for default size and custom size for image.

use this way,

```
$images = get_sub_field('image'); 

 wp_get_attachment_image_src($images, 'full');

 wp_get_attachment_image_src($images, 'medium');

 wp_get_attachment_image_src($images, 'thumbnail');
```